# SSRS expression to DAX powerbi convertion

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, dax, ssrs-2008

IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DivisionOrderType.Value), "",Fields!DivisionOrderType.Value & " " & FormatDateTime(Fields!PrelimDOI.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))

Need of dax formula in powerbi, is it possible? can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try like this...

If(Isblank(DivisionOrderType)," ",DivisonOrderType&" "&Format(PrelimDOI,"DD-MM-YYYY"))

Comment: great..! thanks for the formula!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
IF(ISBLANK(DivisionOrderType), "", DivisionOrderType & " " & FORMAT(PrelimDOI, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

In this example, DivisionOrderType and PrelimDOI are assumed to be column names in the Power BI data model. If these columns have a different name in your data model, you'll need to replace them with the correct column names in the expression.